# Is it possible to make Xbox 360 games using SDL?

Tags: sdl, xbox360, xbox

I've watched Elysian Shadows' video on getting started with game development and in the video, Falco says that you can make a game engine entirely from scratch. Going from his word, XNA seems like "cheating" and I was wondering if there was any way to make Xbox 360 games without XNA, but rather relying on low level libraries such as SDL, along with c++.

Here is the video for reference. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OaxckMNq0eU

Comment: I really don't see how using XNA is 'cheating' it's just a framework. With that mentality you could say SDL is also cheating since you are effectively using it the same way.

Answer (score -1):

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/could-sdl-be-used-to-target-xbox-360

The above question was already answered on the GameDev StackExchange. Basically, the answer is no because "**XNA is C# and DirectX**" whie "*SDL is C and OpenGL*".

I'm probably missing something, so try to do more research on it.